# Laravel cashier with stripe, error checking subscription status

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-cashier

I get the following error when checking subscription status with:

```
$user = User::where('id', '=', \Auth::user()->id)->first();

if ($user->subscribed('main')) <-- error
```

Error:

```
ErrorException in Builder.php line 2405: Call to undefined method
     Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::valid() (View: /var/www/html...

 in Builder.php line 2405
at Builder->__call('valid', array())
at Builder->valid()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'valid'), array()) in Builder.php line 1426
at Builder->__call('valid', array())
at Builder->valid()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'valid'), array()) in Relation.php line 343
at Relation->__call('valid', array()) in Billable.php line 172
at HasMany->valid() in Billable.php line 172
at User->subscribed('main') in BillingsController.php line 58
at BillingsController->index()
```

I don't get any problems using the `$user->onGenericTrial()` and `$user->onTrial()` methods in the same view.

I've created a new subscription using:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->newSubscription('main', 'monthly')->create($creditCardToken);
```

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and Cashier 6.0 . I followed docs here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/billing#checking-subscription-status .

In my user model, I use Laravel\Cashier\Billable; and use Billable; and hasMany on my Subscription model. My Subscription model has the belongsTo User relation

User model

```
<?php namespace App;

use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;

use Carbon\Carbon;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    public $incrementing = true;

    use SoftDeletes;

    use Billable;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = [ ...  'stripe_id', 'card_brand', 'card_last_four', 'trial_ends_at'];


    public function subscription()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Subscription');
    }

    public function getTrialEndsAtAttribute($value)
    {
        $format = $this->getDateFormat();   
        return  Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $value, 'UTC')->setTimezone(\Helper::getTimezone());
    }
```

This is where the error occurs:

https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/6.0/src/Billable.php

```
public function subscribed($subscription = 'default', $plan = null)
{
    $subscription = $this->subscription($subscription);
    if (is_null($subscription)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (is_null($plan)) {
        return $subscription->valid();
    }
    return $subscription->valid() &&
           $subscription->stripe_plan === $plan;
}
```

**Solution:**

Finally found the problem! One must NOT create relationships between User and Subscription models. I had the hasMany relationship on my User model and the belongsTo relationship on the Subscription model. That was the problem.

Comment: Can you post your user model?

Comment: Done, user model was added

Comment: @user3489502 would you post your solution as a separate answer? I think many of us are missing that at the bottom of all your code.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try and run:

```
$user->first()->subscribed('main');
```

See if this throws the same error, The reason im asking this is because the  Illuminate query builder can throw undefined method if the full object is not instantiated.

Im not a laravel pro however i have faced this issue myself on several occasions, Let me give you an example of how i overcome a similar issue today.

return `$user->payments()->first()->fetchMostRecent($customArrayValues)->first();`

Also what does your `$user->subscription();` or `$user->subscription()->first();` return, does this function return what is expected?

As i said im by no means a pro with laravel however i will try and help out the best i can, I am sure more advanced people on here will also provide a helping hand as the query builder error exceptions can be a pain in the back side!

Comment: Thanks @Birdy, `$user->first()->subscribed('main');` gives me the same error, I was already using `first()` on my query when getting `$user`. With `$user->subscription();` , I get the User data, but Subscription is empty.

Comment: Spent hours today on this, thought it might have been an RI problem, but looks like everything is working as it should. Tried this `$user->subscription()->first()`, I get the single subscription I'm looking, but if I do this `$user->subscription()->first()->subscribed('main')`, I get `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::subscribed()` because the Subscription model doesn't use Billable trait. Now if I add `use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;` and `use Billable;` in my Subscription model, I get `true` when I do this `dd($user->subscription()->first()->subscribed('main'))`.

Comment: but it's a bit funky code to get there, and I'm pretty sure that wasn't the intent with Laravel/Cashier. The documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/billing#stripe-configuration) says Billable trait should be added on the User model.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Found the solution (see above).

Comment: Excellent glad you have got it working, i couldnt understand the issue when i come accross something similar and in the end it was to do with elequent returning arrays / collections and the fact i was trying to call a function on a collection not a single user object so would be like  running the function on $user->paid()->get(); as apose to $user->paid()->first();  as the first function then gives me the first record within the collection and thats why my error was being thrown as i didnt realise it was returning several results before i used ->first();  if this makes sense!  Take care.